# how to Invisible one of the item in TRadioGroup?

Tags: delphi

Any idea to make one of the options in TRadioGroup component invisible? (Delphi 7)

[image]

Comment: Without knowing exactly your reason to do it, I supose that you want to remove some option that is either not available or not applicable. So as a general User Interface guideline, I would suggest you to just **disable** it instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it would be more semantic to use `Buttons[]` property instead, so

```
RadioGroup.Buttons[Index].Visible := False
```

and usability-wise, to disable (`Enabled := False`) rather than to hide

Answer (score 4):

```
RadioGroup1.Controls[...].Visible := False;
```

Comment: It wil however leave a blank spot  where the item turn invisible was :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the desired string from the `TRadioGroup.Items` property:

```
RadioGroup1.Items.Delete(IndexHere);
```

Comment: Which moves up the other items by one (so if you use the indexes somewhere else, you need to adjust for that).

Comment: True, because removing the string from the Items property will delete the cooresponding TRadioButton and reposition the remaining buttons accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retain the itemindex of the strings/Items (visible or not) in the radio group you are going to have to keep them somewhere else. So declare a TStringlist that holds all the radiogroup items seperately. Then lookup the index in that stringlist after the radio group selection. something like:

```
RadioGroup: TRadioGroup;
AllRadioItems: TStringList;
fill both... ect


RealIndex := AllRadioItems.IndexOf(RadioGroup.Items[RadioGroup.ItemIndex]);
```

a little overhead but simple and understandable...